# Disable autoplay on a video played in an iFrame from a static resource

Tags: visualforce, static-resources, iframe, video

I have an mp4 training video that I am trying to add to my Account page layout via an inline Visualforce page.  The video is stored as a static resource (Create_New_Contact).  I have successfully added it to the page layout, but I can't seem to figure out how to disable autoplay.  As soon as the page loads, the video starts playing, and nothing I do will stop it.  Here is my code, thanks in advance.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" showHeader="false" showChat="false" sidebar="false">
<iframe width="336" height="189"
    src="{!$Resource.Create_New_Contact}"
    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true">
</iframe>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with your visualforce-page, nor your page layout. It will probably be in your static resource, which is, I presume, a HTML page embedding an external video? Disable it on that HTML page, it could be anything, what kind of video are you loading? how is it displayed in that page? You would have the same problem when opening the html page itself. I can tell you this has nothing to do with salesforce, fix your HTML page.

Comment: Thanks, Pieterjan.  You will have to forgive my ignorance, as I am pretty new to VF/Web development.  My video is an MP4, and I have loaded that directly into the static resource.  I do not have an HTML page.  Does that mean I cannot disable Autoplay?

Comment: Then it will be your browser that automatically loads the MP4, same as you would directly open the MP4 on your computer with your browser. Try the suggestion of Rajowski, this could work, don't forget to add the attribute doctype="html-5.0" to your apex:page tag, as his suggestion is HTML5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead of iframe:

```
<video controls="true">
<source src="{!$Resource.Create_New_Contact}" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Comment: That did the trick.  Thanks to both of you for all your help.

Answer (score -2):

Please try this code this is also responsive in all devices to use.

vote friends

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <video controls="true" class="embed-responsive-item">
      <source src="example.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
</div>
```

Comment: Stack Exchange discourages asking for votes and best answer. The community will provide that feedback where appropriate.

Comment: This answer is very similar to the accepted answer that was given over 3 years ago. Similar answers can be fine, but in those cases I like to see different insight and/or additional information. I feel that this answer would be improved if you went into detail about _how_ this markup prevents autoplay.